# Qual o motivo para uma declaração context.provider no React Native dar erro na compilação?

Tags: react, react-native, react-hooks

Estou tentando usar um contexto global em react native e não estou tendo sucesso.
Mais especificamente, no momento, está dando um erro na compilação que não estou conseguindo entender.

no meu arquivo userContext.ts.

```
import React from "react";

/*** 
 * Valor default do contexto
 ***/
const Login = {
    User: {
        Id: null,
        Name: null,
        Email: null,
        SessionToken: null,
        Avatar: null,
        Session: null,
    },
    setUser: () => {}, // função de inicialização
};

const UserContext = React.createContext(Login);

const UserProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [User, setUser] = useState(Login.User);
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider
            value={{
                User,
                setUser,
            }}
        >
            { children }
        </UserContext.Provider>
   );
};

export default UserContext;
export { UserProvider };
```

apresenta a mensagem de erro a seguir

```
Android Bundling failed 326ms
error: Error: /home/[...]/contexts/userContext.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (30:20)

  28 |     const [User, setUser] = useState(Login.User);
  29 |     return (
> 30 |         <UserContext.Provider
     |                     ^
  31 |             value={{
  32 |                 User,
  33 |                 setUser,
```

Não consigo captar o que está errado, haja vista não há nada de errado no código, eu acho. Fico grato pela a ajuda.

Comment: Parece coisa do typescript. Alguns testes: 1) Mudar o formato do arquivo para .tsx, e não .ts, pois ele pode estar passeando como algo diferente. 2) Apagar o objeto Login e deixar os valores padrão do `UserContext` e `useState` como `null`, puro e simples (em vez de um objeto cujas propriedade são null). Essa segunda opção é mandinga, não tem muito fundamento.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, obrigado, mudei o conteúdo para js puro, mudei a extensão para js e passou, coisas da tecnologia. rs